# Display data in list ball by ball run in Android Studio

Tags: android, json, android-studio, retrofit, android-developer-api

I have this JSON response - how can I handle it?

```
recent_overs_repr": [
                {
                    "overnumber": 15,
                    "ball_repr": [
                        "r0",
                        "r2",
                        "r1",
                        "e1,wd",
                        "w",
                        "r0",
                        "r1"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "overnumber": 14,
                    "ball_repr": [
                        "r1",
                        "r0",
                        "b6",
                        "w",
                        "r0",
                        "r0"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "overnumber": 13,
                    "ball_repr": [
                        "b4",
                        "r0",
                        "r1",
                        "r1",
                        "r0",
                        "r1"
                    ]
                }
            ]
```

Comment: suppose over  14    r1 - 1 run ,r0 - 0run ,b6 - 6 run , w - w , e1,wd - wicket    please help

Comment: explain in detail

Comment: There is a lot of context missing here. What is a "ball by ball run"? Is this data obtained from a sports data feed? What do mean by "handle it"?

Comment: how to handle b4 data display in application

Comment: "ball_repr": [
                        "r0",
                        "r2",
                        "r1",
                        "e1,wd",
                        "w",
                        "r0",
                        "r1"
                    ]                  how to display data overwise

Comment: r repalce  but display 0 runs .... how to replace e1,wd -- but i want to display wd only